# Remap keypad keys to modifiers

Tags: x11, keyboard, xmodmap

I did some research but I couldn't find a working solution:
How can I make my keyboard buttons: <kbd>KP_1</kbd>, <kbd>KP_2</kbd>, <kbd>KP_3</kbd> to work exactly the same as <kbd>Shift_L</kbd>, <kbd>Alt_L</kbd> and <kbd>Control_L</kbd>?

I use Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon.

I want the new keys to work in game Dota 2 (but i don't mind if they will work globally). I tried different things but none of it worked as expected:

#### `xmodmap`

I run in terminal:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 87 = Shift_L"
xmodmap -e "keycode 88 = Alt_L"
xmodmap -e "keycode 89 = Control_L"
```

Results:

- OS: <kbd>KP_1</kbd> and <kbd>KP_2</kbd> work as they should (as <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>), but somehow <kbd>kp_3</kbd> doesn't work as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- Dota 2: none of the <kbd>kp_1</kbd>, <kbd>kp_2</kbd>, <kbd>kp_3</kbd> work as <kbd>Shift</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (why?)

#### `remap.inc` file

I added the following lines to `/etc/console-setup/remap.inc`

```
keycode  79 = Shift
keycode  80 = Alt
keycode  81 = Control
```

and then run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup -phigh
```

Results: doesn't work anywhere. I don't know why these keycodes are different than what "xev" returns, but that's what I found using dumpkeys:

```
sudo dumpkeys | egrep "^keycode.*KP_[123]"
keycode  79 = KP_1            
keycode  80 = KP_2            
keycode  81 = KP_3
```

#### `xbindkeys` + `xte`

I addedd these lines to `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"xte 'key Shift_L'"
    Mod2 + KP_End
```

and ran "xbindkeys" in terminal.
Results: doesn't work anywhere (probably because `Shift_L` is pressed only once - I would like it to be kept pressing when I keep pressing <kbd>KP_1</kbd>, just like the normal <kbd>Shift</kbd> button).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to map new keys as modifiers (like Shift, Ctrl, Alt), using `keycode` with `xmodmap` is not sufficient. You need to do something like:

```
keycode 87 = Shift_L
clear shift
add shift = Shift_L

keycode 88 = Alt_L
clear mod1
add mod1 = Alt_L

keycode 89 = Control_L
clear control
add control = Control_L
```

You have some examples in the `xmodmap(1)` man page. You can put these commands in a `xmodmaprc` file and run `xmodmap xmodmaprc` (instead of several `xmodmap -e` invocations).

Comment: It doesn't work in Dota 2 unfortunately (it works in os though). Any ideas why or how can i make it to work in other apps/games?

Comment: @Kossak Perhaps Dota 2 does low-level keyboard access, which would mean that any remapping would have no effect on it. In such a case, the only thing you might be able to do is to change the Dota 2 configuration if the keycodes are not hardcoded...

Comment: I would do it in the game itself but it doesn't have any option to rebind keys to Shift and Ctrl. In windows i just used external app for it (autohotkey) but it works only on windows.